# Magento 2.3 setup “InstallSchema” script not creating table

Tags: magento, schema, magento2, magento-2.3

I have used setup to create table but script is not creating the table. I have also removed the entry from setup_module table but still, it didn't work. Ive tried migration to declarative schema using `bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1` since its a `Magento 2.3` installation, but the original script needs to work first.

> magento-path/app/code/Folder/CustomModule/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

namespace Folder\CustomModule\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
    */
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
          /**
          * Create table 'shop_ocxe'
          */
          $setup->startSetup();

          $table = $setup->getConnection()
              ->newTable($setup->getTable('shop_ocxe'))
              ->addColumn(
                  'id',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                  null,
                  ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                  'Shop ID'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'url',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  ['nullable' => false],
                  'Url'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'name',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  ['nullable' => false],
                  'Name'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'phrase',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  [],
                  'Phrase'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'logo',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  [],
                  'Logo'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'banner',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  [],
                  'Banner'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'author',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  ['nullable' => false],
                  'Author'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'author_photo',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  255,
                  ['nullable' => false],
                    'Author Photo'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'desc',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  '64k',
                  [],
                  'Desc'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'status',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                  null,
                  ['nullable' => false, 'default' => 1],
                  'Status'
              )
              ->addColumn(
                  'created_at',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                  null,
                  ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                  'Created At'
              )->addColumn(
                  'updated_at',
                  \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                  null,
                  ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                  'Updated At'
              )->setComment("Shop Table");
          $setup->getConnection()->createTable($table);

          $setup->endSetup();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating from the scripts to `declarative schema` worked for me. For anyone using Magento 2.3 and above it seems to be a must.

Table Scheme Example:

```
<table name="catalog_product_entity_datetime" resource="default" engine="innodb"
           comment="Catalog Product Datetime Attribute Backend Table">
    <column xsi:type="int" name="value_id" padding="11" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Value ID"/>
    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="attribute_id" padding="5" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" default="0" comment="Attribute ID"/>
    <column xsi:type="smallint" name="store_id" padding="5" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" default="0" comment="Store ID"/>
    <column xsi:type="int" name="entity_id" padding="10" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="false" default="0" comment="Entity ID"/>
    <column xsi:type="datetime" name="value" on_update="false" nullable="true" comment="Value"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
        <column name="value_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ATTR_ID_EAV_ATTR_ATTR_ID" table="catalog_product_entity_datetime" column="attribute_id" referenceTable="eav_attribute" referenceColumn="attribute_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CAT_PRD_ENTT_DTIME_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID" table="catalog_product_entity_datetime" column="entity_id" referenceTable="catalog_product_entity" referenceColumn="entity_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="foreign" referenceId="CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_STORE_ID_STORE_STORE_ID" table="catalog_product_entity_datetime" column="store_id" referenceTable="store" referenceColumn="store_id" onDelete="CASCADE"/>
    <constraint xsi:type="unique" referenceId="CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ENTITY_ID_ATTRIBUTE_ID_STORE_ID">
        <column name="entity_id"/>
        <column name="attribute_id"/>
        <column name="store_id"/>
    </constraint>
    <index referenceId="CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_ATTRIBUTE_ID" indexType="btree">
        <column name="attribute_id"/>
    </index>
    <index referenceId="CATALOG_PRODUCT_ENTITY_DATETIME_STORE_ID" indexType="btree">
        <column name="store_id"/>
    </index>
</table>
```

See more: [Magento docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/db-schema.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

```
 1. delete Jk_Ocxe entry from setup_module table .
 2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

I have tried and table is creating on my system.

Comment: Thanks, I did the above steps, but it seems to be a version compatibility issue instead of a script issue. Magento 2.3 just ignore my script for some reason.

Comment: @James : have you getting any error or something when you run upgrade cmd?

Comment: Not really, that's kind of frustrating. I saw someone's post with the same issue (even worse - custom module stopped working from 2.2 to 2.3) and only updating to declarative schema worked. Luckly for me it did the trick too.